# LaTeX is moving my section to a new page

Tags: sectioning, floats, page-breaking

I'm just wondering, why LaTeX always moves my section to a new page, even without using the new page command. This will look like the following, and does only happen for this particular section

[image]

Do you have any general hint for me about what could be wrong? Do you need to whole code of the LaTeX-document to elaborate this problem? The strange thing is, that it doesn't happen for the other subsections and sections, so obviously it doesn't have to do anything with the general Latex template...

Here is a small excerpt of the file

```
dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT 
\begin{table}[hbt]
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{rcrcrcrc}
            \toprule
            \textbf{bla} & \phantom{-} & \textbf{bla} & \phantom{-} & \textbf{bla} & \phantom{-} & \textbf{bla} \\  
            \cmidrule{1-1} \cmidrule{3-3} \cmidrule{5-5} \cmidrule{7-7}  
      50  &&  35.6     &&   111    &&    67.92\\
     100  &&  35.2     &&   12    &&   621.018\\
     200  &&  16.8     &&   330    &&   6111.422\\
     ........ SOME MORE DATA .............

            \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{BLABLA}\label{tab:bla}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{02clippers.jpg} 
\caption{blaaaaaa}  
\label{fig:clipperss}           
\end{figure}
Die Grafik \autoref{fig:clipperss} dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%====================================================================================================
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Stand der Technik}
\label{sec:Stand-der-Technik}
dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT dBLA BLA BLA BLA SOME TEXT
```

Using latest TeCnicCenter with MiKTeX and TeXify for outputting under Windows 8.1.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `[htb]` positioning specifiers?

Comment: Unfortunately it's still the same without it (removed iit for the figure AND for the table)

Comment: Would be easier to answer if you could trim your code down to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). You don't have a `\clearpage` in there either?

Comment: looks like a separate floating page, where no regular text is put. It happened to me when I had a lot of tables in line with not much text inbetween. You could try to change `[htb]` to `[!h]`, or if you want to set the distances yourself, load `float` and use `[H]`.

Comment: No `\clearpage` being used, no. @Torbjorn: If nothing helps, I'll do that, but for the moment I thought maybe someone has a quick idea about it or it's something which happens more often and therefore would be a known problem in latex communities. @Tom: Maybe I'm just trying to put the code to include the graphic to another place within the document and see what happens then.

Comment: Oh, well... I did what I said and it fixed it. Don't know why but would have been easier to trying that before I posted here. But nevermind... So what I did is: I just put thr code of the figure AFTER the last paragraph in the first section and thus just before  `\section{Stand der Technik}` and now everything is working alright.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The section heading prevents page break until after a line of the following paragraph, so TeX will take the heading on to the top of a page as there isn't room at the bottom of the first page you show.

So the question is really why did latex insert a float page in the second page image shown.

Without example code one can only guess, but one of these may be true.

- You have `\clearpage` before the section (probably not, but has to be said for completeness).
- You have `\FloatBarrier` from the `placeins` package before the section. (This does `\clearpage` if there are pending floats, so would come to the above in this case.)
- You have `placeins` package loaded with option `[section]`. (This adds `\FloatBarrier` to every section, so comes to the above.)
- LaTeX just decided to make a float page. (It will do this if it has gathered "enough" material to insert a float page. "enough" here means more than `\floatpagefraction` which is set to 0.5 in `article` class. Your image looks to be less than half a page but perhaps it has hidden white space within the image (eg it's an A4 image, but white at the bottom half) or you are not using `article` or `\floatpagefraction` has been reset.)
- Something else is true.

Comment: Sorry to resurrect an old post, but is there a way to use `placeins` with the `[section]` command and still not have LaTeX kick the section to a new page?

Comment: @grfrazee `placeins` forces a `\clearpage` if there are any floats pending, (that is all it does) so if there are floats to be flushed out then you will get a page break before the section. (or use a different package)